# Flags- and non-flags-variant of an enum

Tags: c#, coding-style, enums

Let's say I need both an enum both in a flags and in a non-flags variant.

- Option 1: I could duplicate everything:

  ```
  enum Color { Red, Blue, Green }

  [Flags]
  enum Colors {
      None = 0,
      Red = 1,
      Blue = 2,
      Green = 4
  }

  // use cases
  Color currentColor;
  Colors supportedColors;
  ```
- Option 2: I could just use the Flags variant for everything:

  ```
  Colors currentColor; // ugly, since neither "None" nor "Red | Blue" should be valid
  ```

I don't like either of these: In Option 1, `Color.Red`, and `Colors.Red` are completely unrelated, which might require binding code. In addition, I'd have to keep the two enums synchronized. The drawback of Option 2 is obvious. What I'd actually like is something like

```
enum Colors = Flag set of Color;
```

Is there a more elgant solution to this requirement?

Comment: Can you please expand on the use cases? Do you ever need to compare `supportedColors` with `currentColor`?

Comment: @Oded: Yes, it would be great to be able to do something like `bool currentColorIsSupported = (currentColor And supportedColor <> 0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply use the `[Flags]` version for everything, and simply ensure in a few places that it is only a single value. You **need** to do that either way, because even without `[Flags]` the following is valid:

```
var flags = (Color)47; // why not
```

So you need to check that the `Color` is one you were expecting *anyway*. The `[Flags]` will only help serialization/parsing.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible drawback of option 2 is running out of bits. If that's your problem, a flags enum is not suitible for you at all. Instead, make supported colors a `HashSet<Color>`

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had same problem. Solved by option 2, with simple check:

```
bool IsColorValid(Color color)
{
    return (color != 0 && (color & (color - 1)) == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Definitely do not make two enums called Color and Colors (option 1). This would make your code very confusing.**

Unless I'm missing something, I don't think option 2 is so ugly. In general, it's reasonable to initialize a system parameter to a default value "None" prior to being set at runtime.